# printf - Can I pass all the variadic arguments as a pointer instead of one-by-one on the stack?

Tags: c, printf

I have a binary logs system that efficiently writes just the variadic printf arguments to a file at runtime, which is later post-processed to produce the text logs.

My post-processing tool that produces the text logs needs to read each printf argument into a variable, just so it can be passed on the stack to printf.

For example, to produce the text for the call to:

```
my_binary_printf("here's an int: %d, here's a float %f, here's a char: %c", i, f, c);
```

from the binary file where the int, the float, and the char from runtime are kept,
I need to do something like:

```
char *binary_data;  // mmap-ed from the binary file produced at runtime
int param0 = *((int*) &(binary_data[0]));
float param1 = *((float*) &(binary_data[4]));
char param2 = *((char*) &(binary_data[8]));
printf(the_format_string, param0, param1, param2);
```

Is there a way to pass all the printf parameters as a pointer to the data? Like:

```
cool_printf(the_format_string, binary_data);
```

My motivation for wanting such a solution is faster post-processing thanks to less copying of the data.

I don't need to support machines with different endianness at the moment.

I'm very open to using an alternative printing library (like fastformat, or Boost's facilities) if it has the feature I'm looking for.

Comment: vsprintf is what you are looking for.

Comment: Possible strict aliasing issues.

Comment: Worth noting that this isn't going to make you any faster. The time is in processing the format, not copying a couple of floats. I wouldn't be at all surprised if it was slower.

Comment: what is `binary_data`? and how the offset `4` comes?

Comment: `va_list` is often just a pointer, with `va_arg` incrementing the pointer, so you could write some code to access all the arguments from there. (Not portably, of course, but you say you don't need that.) But it would still involve parsing the format string to know how many bytes to read.

Comment: @Klaus, I added those tags because I'm open to using c++, boost or fastformat. If that's not a good use of tags I'll remove them.

Comment: @Klaus, thanks for your feedback. I removed those tags.

Comment: forget about this level microoptimization. Comparing to the printf itself the time you copy the parameters is negligible

Comment: @appleapple, I added a line showing what binary_data is. I hope it clarifies it. In practice, the offsets come from the post-processing tool actually iterating over the format string, and generating a call to an appropriate template function for each format specifier it encounters, which prints the text up to and including a single format specifier, and then increments the pointer it receives.

Comment: @Eli_B if *that* tool have parsed the format, you can simply print within that tool. I don't see a need for a separated function.

Comment: @P__J__ : I don't think it is intended to be an optimisation, but rather a way of encoding an arbitrary structure of the binary blob in the format string to avoid separately unpacking it then passing to printf.

Comment: If emitting data via `printf()` is your performance bottleneck, **don't use `printf()`**.  You **have** profiled your entire application and actually *measured* performance and located your performance bottlenecks that way?

Comment: @AndrewHenle : It is true that it will have negligible performance impact.  However it has a significant convenience/maintenance impact - to encode the structure of the binary data in the format string alone.

Comment: @Clifford I think you're underestimating the maintenance impact of reimplementing `printf()`-style format string parsing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle : No reimplementation necessary - as described in my answer.  You just need to parse the part of the specifier that describes the width (although strings are problematic perhaps), ignoring the output formatting modifiers. Use that to extract the data, then pass the data and the complete format specifier to `printf()`.  It is still non-trivial however that is true, which is why in my answer I suggest it is only worth it if you need to do a lot of this on a lot of very different structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution will involve writing your own format string parser that interprets the format specifiers with data width to extract from the binary blob, such that each format specifier caused the data index to be incremented, and the correct type to be extracted and printed.

Superficially the function [vprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vprintf/) appears close to what you need, but is not viable.  It takes a single `va_list` argument which normally you create from a `...` var-arg list using using `va_start`, but in your case the input is not a var-arg list, so it is unlikely to work directly on the binary data without first unpacking your binary data - other than by dumb luck, and even then certainly not portable.

The (or at least one) problem with `vprintf` is a var-arg list is unlikely to be aligned in the same manner as your binary blob; stacked arguments are likely to have fixed alignment and not be contiguous.

The approach I'd suggest here is to parse the format string, print each non-format specifier character directly, extract format specifiers completely (with all modifiers), determine the width/type from the specifier, extract that much data into an appropriate data type, print that single data item using the *whole* format specifier, and increment the data index by the width.  Continue like that for the entire format string.  It is a lot of work - you'd have to be doing a lot of this to justify the effort - but you only write it once, and it would be generic so may make maintenance simpler.

Note:

> My motivation for wanting such a solution is faster post-processing thanks to less copying of the data.

That is a poor reason; it will have negligible performance impact.  It is better justified by the simplicity and convenience of encoding arbitrary data structure of the binary blob in the format string.  This may have a significant development, readability and maintenance impact if you have a lot of code like this with many varying data structures to encode.

Comment: Note that  `...` is not a var-arg list. It is just an indication to the compiler that a variable number of arguments may follow in the function call. The macros just work by taking the adress of the first non-`...` argument, incrementing that with its type-size yielding the first (next) argument. As such, it is viabe to pass the address of this first non-`...` argument and passing that to a funtion expecting a variable argument list as you have now passed the stack position of the first argument. the va-macros in the called function now work on this argument that it dereferences.

Comment: The variables don`t even need to be on the stack. I think a function that he seeks is possible (I just don't go into the depth of writing it now).

Comment: I withdraw my previous comment: alignment is the issue, unless he would write the data in an aligned manner, e.g. write a char as an int. Alignment is implementation dependent and so is not portable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Clifford. My current implementation is really almost identical to your suggested approach. I was just wondering whether I could forego iterating over the format string and printing data items one at a time. Hopefully, one day this logging system would be open-sourced and I'll be able to show you :)

Comment: @Eli_B The [glibc code that parses format strings](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c) is well over 2,000 lines, and is extremely complex, involving large, complex macros and fully seven different jump tables. A bug-free reimplementation of that is somewhere between impossible and completely extraneous. What happens in the future when someone else adds a format specifier to the format string that isn't covered by the necessarily-limited parsing that does get reimplemented?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, hopefully nobody has to reimplement that thing. My implementation only parses the format string to segment it into substrings that contain a single format specifier. I pass those substrings to printf, which fully parses them. I have the benefit of assuming the format string itself is sane, because my_binary_printf is decorated with __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2))), so bad formats won't hopefully fail to compile.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie : regarding `...` I appreciate the semantics, I was merely using it as a short-hand to indicate the `va_start` necessarily relies on `...`; if you were to have a function `fn( const char* fmt, int x, int y )` and in it use `va_start( vl, fmt)` `vl` may not refer to `x` and `y` since they may have been passed in registers. `...` ensures they are referrable by a `va_list`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle : You have possibly misunderstood my proposal.  I am not suggesting writing a format string parser, only parsing the information necessary to determine data size - the output formatting remains the responsibility of `printf()`.  If I get time later I'll add an implementation (possibly partial) that will make it clearer.

Comment: @Eli_B : I don't think it matters iterating the format string - you write it once, hide it in a library and forget about the internals - how do you think printf does it for example!?  This is not where you need to optimise.

Comment: Thanks again @Clifford, I've accepted your answer. I think my question is well-stated, and it did generate interest. I wonder why it was down-voted.

Comment: @Eli_B In the title at least, you appear to be asking whether printf specifically can do that; to which the answer is clearly "no".  The answer to the question in the title is to use vprintf, the question in the body differs significantly.  These are possible reasons for a downvote.  However in my experience if you ask a "Can I ...?" question to which the answer is either no, or obvious from documentation, you will attract downvotes.  Better to ask "How can I...?", avoid making suggestions of your own, and never to ask whether it can be done using a single well documented standard function.

Comment: Thanks again @Clifford! I'll keep it in mind. I did know vprintf wasn't what I'm looking for, but I was hoping for creative ideas, if not for printf uses than maybe of the form "No, but you can instead ...". Should I change the title now to something like "How can I pass the parameters to a string formatting operation as a pointer to contiguous memory?" to better serve people in the future?